Which locker is the Lieutenant's?
In the Boys in Blue heist in stealth, one of the bonus objectives is to place a bug in the Lt's locker. However, so far aside from just opening every locker and seeing which one has a "place bug" prompt, I haven't found a way to figure out which one is his. Is there any way to tell which locker belongs to the Lt?

You're not the only one struggling with this.
If you press and hold TAB, it will show you a description of the objective, which includes the locker number.
